# Is Jabber the same thing as XMPP?

Tags: instant-messaging, jabber, xmpp

I find conflcting information on this subject. Are they the same thing? I've read that Jabber is "based" on XMPP.

For example: The chat client "Pidgin" has a box for XMPP but seemingly not for Jabber. Yet, it seems to support it.

What's the difference between XMPP and Jabber?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/Jabber_Programmer%27s_Guide

> The architecture of the Jabber network
>   is similar to email while a Jabber
>   server conforms an email server
>   (server.com) and Jabber clients
>   conforms email clients
>   (user@server.com). The difference is
>   that everything happens (by
>   definition: nearly) in realtime over a
>   persistent XML-TCP stream. In example
>   this makes it possible that other
>   (authorized) users can see your online
>   presence. In addition to that servers
>   can offer specialised services, in
>   example a user directory
>   (users.server.com) or a weather agent
>   (weather.server.com). XMPP is the
>   architecture/protocol the network is
>   based on.

And specifically:

> What is the difference between Jabber and XMPP?
>   Since 2004 XMPP is the IETF-approved instant messaging and presence protocol. XMPP is based on the Jabber protocol that evolves since 1998. Basically programming Jabber software today means programming XMPP compliant software.

Comment: This answer is **wrong**. How did it get 18 upvotes? See the next answer.

Comment: Yep, it's wrong because **Jabber is not the name of an implementation.**

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Am I reading this wrong? The first blurb says "XMPP is the architecture/protocol the [Jabber] network is based on." The second one says "XMPP is based on the Jabber protocol." A bit of a chicken and egg problem here, no?

Answer (score 18):

**XMPP is the new name, Jabber the old.** So yes, they refer to the same protocol stack.

[XMPP is used as name since 2002:](http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/history/)

> In late 2001 and early 2002, prominent members of the Jabber community
>   decided to once again submit the base **Jabber** protocols to the IETF,
>   this time as an official submission by the JSF. The first submission
>   was made in February 2002 as an informational Internet-Draft (text |
>   HTML). Following on the success of this submission, it was decided to
>   explore the possibility of forming an IETF Working Group devoted to
>   formalization of the base Jabber protocols, under the **neutral name of**
>    **Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP)**.

Maybe some background: The name/term 'Jabber' was bought by Cisco and is now a registered trademark of Cisco.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference between Jabber and XMPP?
>
> Since 2004 XMPP is the IETF-approved instant messaging and presence
>   protocol. XMPP is based on the Jabber protocol that evolves since
>   1998. Basically programming Jabber software today means programming XMPP compliant software.

According to : [http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/Jabber_Programmer's_Guide](http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/Jabber_Programmer%27s_Guide)

It looks like as an improved version of Jabber protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Note that "Jabber" is a [registered trademark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark) (JABBER®):

http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/xsf/jabber-trademark/

> JABBER® is a registered trademark licensed through the XMPP Standards Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

### Jabber and XMPP

> We use the terms **Jabber** and **XMPP** interchangeably. These technologies were originally developed by **Jeremie Miller** and the **Jabber open source community** in 1998–1999. When the community submitted its core protocols to the Internet **Engineering Task Force (IETF)** in 2002, it chose the name E**X**tensible **M**essaging and **P**resence **P**rotocol” to distinguish the protocol from the broader technology and developer community. You can think of the relationship as **XMPP is to Jabber as HTTP is to the Web** The term Jabber was proactively trademarked by Jabber, Inc. (now part of Cisco Systems, Inc.) in 2000 to protect the open source community, but the XSF sublicenses the term for use in open source projects and other community activities.

Comment: Please add source/link if available.

Answer (score -1):

What about this, a well written back in **2006** [Jabber vs. XMPP](https://stpeter.im/journal/957.html)

Comment: -1 because this should either quote/summarize the message of the linked site or be a comment